# Extremely large class set for support vector machine (SVM) classification

Tags: svm, multi-class

For a problem where I have tens of thousands of different classes, wouldn't it be very inefficient to use the typical multiclass methods? If I were to do one vs all, wouldn't that mean that I have would have to run through every individual classes before determining if a new set of data belongs to a certain class? That would be computationally very slow.

Is there a way to get around this? Should I even use SVM's when it gets to such a size?

Comment: How many training samples do you have per class? Do you really have tens of thousands of significantly/practically different classes? Maybe share some more information about the problem.

Comment: @B_Miner I can have maybe 100 samples per class, but yes I have tens of thousands of different classes. This is an object recognition application, so there is really an infinite amount of classes I could have.

Comment: A million records might be difficult to hold in memory, if based on other posts you are using R. It seems you will need as many as possible (cases) given that large number of classes. Is there any hierarchical nature to the data where by you could model a smaller subset of classes and then depending on that prediction, model a subset of the overall classes which "roll-up" to that higher level class group?

Comment: @B_Miner i see what you mean, but right now I don't see any way of making any hierarchy in my data. I'm also using matlab right now, not R.

Comment: How about using Gaussian processes instead?

Comment: Have you tried glmnet?

Answer (score 3):

I would use the [DAGSVM](http://complexity.enm.bris.ac.uk/cig/pubs/2000/dagsvm.pdf) approach, which constructs a tree of pairwise classifiers.  If you have only 100 patterns per class, but tens of thousands of classes, a lot of the pairwise classifiers will have no training data and hence not every possible pairwise classifier will need to be constructed.

However, more importantly, it is hard to consider a problem with such a large number of classes, where the classification is not in some sense hierarchical.  A better approach would be to first construct a classifier to classify each pattern into broad categories (representing a set of related classes) and then iteratively refine patterns withing each broad category to identify the finer distinctions between classes.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look a Vowpal Wabbit. It's an implementation of Stochasic Gradient Decent, which is very efficient for large scale datasets. If you choose the right parameters it can mimic a SVM (hinge-loss). It also includes a reduction called [Error-Correcting Tournaments](http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3176), which is quite efficient for multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

There are classification models that are inherently multiclass, without error-correcting codes or one-vs-rest. Some popular ones are Neural Networks, Linear Discriminant Analysis, Random Forests, Naive Bayes and kNN. The training time usually goes up a little, but it's far more efficient than one-vs-rest classification. There's a multiclass formulation of structural SVM, that worth mentioning. Though I haven't used it myself.